Some good practice for upper level linear algebra?
Last semester I took my second course in linear algebra (aptly used Axler's book) and got a good treatment of proof based linear algebra. However I didn't feel like I got very good practice for anything past inner products and the various factorizations and decompositions, mostly since the proofs in the book are very abstract. Are there any good problem sets that rely on these topics but present the problem in a more concrete way / give a nice real world example? For example, SVD image compression is a nice real world application of singular value decomposition and thinking through the problem and implementing it in code helped me understand SVD better than just doing some abstract proof in the book. Any pointers to such problems would be much appreciated!

Strang's Linear Algebra and Learning from Data gives the topics in context.
